# Replace the model based on other fields in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a model in c#

```
public class TypeChanger  {
    string Name { get; set; }        
    T Identity { get; set; }        
}
```

if the name is apple the datatype of Identity should be the tree and need to set values of tree object.

```
public class Tree  {
    string TreeName { get; set; }        
    string TreeValue { get; set; }        
}
```

Suppose the name is Car, the data type of Identity should be Car.
and need to set the object as Car

```
public class Car 
{
    string CarName { get; set; }        
    string CarValue { get; set; }        
}
```

is it poosible in c#?

Comment: is `TypeChanger` a generic class like: `public class TypeChanger <T> {` ? The rest is a little unclear to me still. Do you want to implement a method in TypeChanger that initiates the values? why did you post the class `Tree` twice? did you want to post the `Car` class?

Comment: could you please post an attempt where you try to use `TypeChanger` ? the use cases are not clear to me yet